# Integration over non-orientable Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, covering-spaces

I am confused a bit by the following theorem that integrates over non-orientable manifold. How is that possible? (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6128/272127)).

**Theorem.** Let $M^n$ be a compact Riemannian non-orientable manifold, and $\omega$ a
differential 1-form. Let $\pi:(\widetilde{M},\tilde{g})\to (M,g)$ be the two-sheeted covering map, where $\tilde{g}=\pi^*g$ and let $\widetilde{A}=\pi^*A$. Then
$$\int_\widetilde{M}\tilde{\delta} \widetilde{\omega}\widetilde{dV}=2\int_M\delta\omega dV.$$

Comment: What's $\delta$?

Comment: co-differential.

Comment: And what is $dV$? It's not the volume form of $M$, because $M$ has no volume form.... so... what is it?

Comment: It should be a density. A $n$-density on a vector space is an object $\omega\colon V^{\times n} \to \Bbb R$ that transforms under $A^*\omega = |\det A|\omega$ as opposed to $A^*\omega = (\det A) \omega$ like what happens with volume forms. In particular, a $n$-density does not have to be multilinear. In any case, for a non-orientable manifold one integrates against a field of $n$-densities.

Comment: The absolute value is required precisely to make the change-of-variable formula hold, as that is what makes the definition via gluing integrals against elements of a partition of unity work.

Comment: Nevertheless, as I commented elsewhere, I believe that $\delta\omega\,dV$ is a well-defined $n$-form, since locally both $\delta$ and $dV$ change sign when we change orientation. $\delta\omega\,dV = (\pm)d(\star\omega)$ is an exact form, but I suppose that to apply Stokes's Theorem without worry we can pass to the orientation double-cover.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Could you pleas extend your comment to an answer? You meant that $dV$ is a Riemann volume form? I am interested to see your answer.

Comment: And you are saying that without considering IvoTerek comment one can integrated?

Comment: @Ivo: I agree that one needs to take $|dV|$ as a density. However, in this case, unless I'm mistaken, the function $\delta\omega$ is not well-defined; it too switches sign when we change orientation. So multiplying by a density won't give something well-defined to integrate.

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to consider the case when $M$ is connected. Since all what you care about are integrals, just choose an open topological disk $U\subset M$ whose complement has measure zero, then pick an orientation on $U$ any way you want. For instance, you can take $U$ to be the complement to the cut-locus of a point in $M$. (If you do not like this, observe that $M$ is a connected sum of an oriented surface and the projective plane. Hence, $M$ contains a 1-sided smooth loop $c$ such that $M'=M-c$ is orientable. You can use $M'$ instead of a disk $U$.)

This will define a volume form $dV$, the Hodge star and $\delta$ on $U$. Then check that the integrand
$$
\delta\omega dV
$$
is independent of the chosen orientation on $U$ (you will be changing the sign twice) and the integral
$$
\int_U \delta\omega dV 
$$
is independent of the choice of $U$ (since $M\setminus U$ has measure zero). This is how you make sense of    the integral
$$
\int_M \delta\omega dV.  
$$

Now, consider the 2-fold covering $\pi$ and observe that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ has two components $U_1, U_2$ such that $\pi|_{U_i}: U_i\to U$ is a diffeomorphism, $i=1,2$. Both integrals
$$
\int_{U_i} \tilde\delta\tilde\omega \widetilde{dV}$$
will equal to
$$
\int_U \delta\omega dV. 
$$
Thus, you get your formula.

The same trick works in higher dimensions as well.

Comment: Is this true in higher dimensions?  `(If you do not like this, observe that M is a connected sum of an oriented surface and the projective plane)`

Comment: No, this is false in higher dimensions, even in dimension 3. A small correction: Among surfaces there is one exception, the Klein bottle, which is the connected sum of two projective planes.

Comment: please see that am I right about orientation: The integral of a non-orientable manifold is similar to integral of $\int_{-a}^a\sin(t)dt$ which is zero and we should calculate $\int_{-a}^a|\sin(t)|$ or $2\int_{0}^a\sin(t)dt$ for real amount of area. Right?

Comment: @C.F.G: I do not know what you mean by "The integral of a non-orientable manifold." What are you planning to integrate? I suggest you read a differential topology/geometry book which discusses differential forms and integration. There is also a theory of integration of densities. This is definitely not the same as the integral of $\sin(t)$. Also, none of these notions will directly address the question you asked in your post (as is clear from the comments).