# Why do we need orientation to integrate on a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, orientation

In my differential geometry course we are studying the integration of compactly supported $n$-forms and I do not really get why we need our manifold to be oriented. Indeed, we define the integral of an $n$-form $\Omega$ as
$$\int_M \Omega = \sum_i \int_{\varphi(U_i)} (\varphi_i^{-1})^*(\theta_i\Omega)$$
for $\{\theta_i\}$ some partition of unity subordinated to an open cover by domains of charts of an atlas compatible with the orientation. But it seems to me that we only need a local orientation on each domain of charts $U_i$ which is always possible on a manifold (actually, I'm not sure about that but intuitively we can define an orientation on each sufficiently small neighborhood of the Moebius band for example). What could possibly go wrong in this definition of the integral with a non-orientable manifold ?

Comment: I think if you pick two charts of the same open subset whose orientations aren't compatible then the results of integrating using them will differ by a sign. It's a generalization of how $\int_a^b = - \int_b^a$. You need an orientation to fix the choice of sign. Without it you can only integrate densities, not $n$-forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_on_a_manifold

Comment: without orientation your result will be inconsistent: choosing a different, but compatible atlas, with random orientation in each chart then the integral will had random signs. However, as @QiaochuYuan said you can ever integrate densities in a manifold, also in non-orientable ones as the Klein bottle or the Mobius strip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the notion of density really needed to define integration on nonorientable manifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6128/is-the-notion-of-density-really-needed-to-define-integration-on-nonorientable-ma)